# Check if a JComponent hasMouseListener()

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, mouselistener, jcomponent

Is it possible to check if a `JComponent` already has a `MouseListener` attached to it?

For example, I am trying to create the `hasMouseListener()` method:

```
JComponent jComponent = getJComponent();
hasMouseListener(jComponent); //should be false
jComponent.addMouseListener(this);
hasMouseListener(jComponent); //should be true
```

An alternative solution would be a way to `getMouseListener()` so that I could check for `null`.

Comment: Have you looked at the API [index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index-files/index-7.html)?

Comment: @kdgregory No i have not. never knew that existed. thanks!!  I was so close. getMouseListeners(), not getMouseListener()!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kdgregory informed me, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index-files/index-7.html exists!

jComponent.getMouseListeners() returns an array of all its MouseListeners.  From there, I can just check its size.

Comment: Well, it can have one listener other that the component you suppose it has, so the size alone won't help. If you want to know if a specific component has been added as listener you'll have too loop though the array.